# How to draw a grid of spheres in increasing order in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

[image: Grid of images]

I've been trying to draw a grid of spheres in increasing order of radius (Image link above) but then all the loops I've tried have been failing. I made the loop below because I thought for one value of x, the y values are incremented and drawn fully and then the x gets incremented and the whole process repeats. But then that doesn't work. What changes should I make?

'a' is a variable belonging to class that contains the coordinates and radius of a sphere.

```
a.x = -500, a.y = -500, a.z = 0, a.r=0;

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++, a.x += 30, a.r++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++, a.y += 30, a.r++)
        drawSphere(a.x + (2 * a.r), a.y, a.z, a.r);
```

Comment: It'd help to know what `drawSphere` does and how you're supposed to use it. Why not focus on getting the data right independent of the `drawSphere` call?

Comment: "drawSphere(double x, double y, double z, double r)"
The first three are the coordinates and the third is the radius. The function draws a sphere with the given data.

Comment: You should be using it correctly then, but I think your approach is wrong, you never reset `y` per loop. Why not get rid of `a` which is the source of confusion and compute `x`, `y` and `r` as a function of `i and `j`?

Comment: I don't understand the "use 'a' as a fn. of 'i' an 'j' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive the values rather than trying to manipulate some kind of counter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    drawSphere(a.x + i * 30, a.y + j * 30, a.z, a.r + i + j);
```

"As a function of" is a mathematical term meaning the final value of `x` you need can be computed from the `a.x` and `i` values, there's no other input necessary. Here it's effectively:

```
x = a.x + i * 30
```

Comment: I did that. It makes the code simpler, but the output is still not the desired output.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.